# Comparing two lists and outputting the bounds of shared consecutive ranges

Tags: python

Sorry if the title is a bit obtuse, I can't think of a better way to phrase it. I need to compare two lists, listA and listB. listB will always be either identical to listA or contain some of the same numbers, there will never be a number in listB that is not in listA. I need to find the extremes of all the ranges of consecutive numbers that are in listB. These are not always integers. So say I have the following two lists:

```
    listA = [1, 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 17.75, 18, 20, 21, 22, 25]
    listB = [1, 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 10, 15, 16, 17, 17.75, 18, 22, 25]
```

I would want to get the following output:

```
    [[1, 4], [10], [15, 18], [22, 25]]
```

Comment: have you tried something than you can share with us?

Comment: 22 and 25 are not consecutive numbers, yet you added them to the range list that forms the last element of `listB`. Why is that?

Comment: @Ajax1234 Yeah, I wish I could think of a better term. I don't necessarily mean consecutive as in 1,2,3,4, I mean consecutive as in what numbers are consecutive in the first list. so if listA had something like 22, 25, 26, 28, 300 and listB had that same range, the output for that particular range of numbers would be [22, 300]. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
listA = [1, 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 17.75, 18, 20, 21, 22, 25]
listB = [1, 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 10, 15, 16, 17, 17.75, 18, 22, 25]

output = []
currentlist = []
lowerbound = 0
for i in range(0,len(listA)):
    if listA[i] in listB:
        currentlist.append(listA[i])
    else:
        if len(currentlist) > 0:
            if currentlist[0] == currentlist[-1]:
                output.append([currentlist[0]])
            else:
                output.append([currentlist[0], currentlist[-1]])
        currentlist = []
if len(currentlist) > 0:
    if currentlist[0] == currentlist[-1]:
        output.append([currentlist[0]])
    else:
        output.append([currentlist[0], currentlist[-1]])
currentlist = [] 
print(output)
```

It's not very efficient but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
listA = [1, 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 17.75, 18, 20, 21, 22, 25]
listB = [1, 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 10, 15, 16, 17, 17.75, 18, 22, 25]

a = b = 0

ranges = []

def valid():
    return a < len(listA) and b < len(listB)


while valid():
    while valid() and listA[a] != listB[b]:
        a += 1
    current_range = [listA[a]]
    while valid() and listA[a] == listB[b]:
        a += 1
        b += 1
    if listA[a - 1] != current_range[0]:
        current_range.append(listA[a - 1])
    ranges.append(current_range)

print(ranges)  # [[1, 4], [10], [15, 18], [22, 25]]
```